# Showing infinite direct sum of Banach spaces with a certain norm is a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces

Given a family $(A_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of Banach spaces, let $\bigoplus_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$ be the set of all $(a_{\lambda})\in\prod_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$ such that $||(a_{\lambda})||=\sup_{\lambda}||a_{\lambda}||<\infty$. I am trying to show that $\bigoplus_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$ is complete but I am stuck somewhere.

What I did was to take a Cauchy sequence $(a_{\lambda,n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\bigoplus_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$ and saw that for each $\lambda$ I have a Cauchy sequence in $A_{\lambda}$, which converges to some $a_{\lambda}\in A_{\lambda}$. So I have a candidate for the limit in $\bigoplus_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$ but I'm missing something in trying to show that I have convergence in $\bigoplus_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$. In fact, I'm not sure whether that candidate is in fact in $\bigoplus_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$.

Comment: Hint: Recall, or reread, a proof that $\ell^\infty$ is a Banach space.

Comment: Indeed that was what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped!  You could post your solution as an answer, if you like.

Comment: Just a curious question, why this is called a direct sum, it looks like a product to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness, I post the proof here. The first two facts are valid for all metric spaces.

1. If a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, it converges.
2. Every Cauchy sequence contains a subsequence (denoted $\{x_n\}$ here) such that $$d(x_n,x_{n+1})\le 2^{-n},\quad n\in\mathbb{N} \tag{1}$$
   (Note that $(1)$ implies being Cauchy.)

So, it suffices to prove that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\bigoplus_{\lambda}A_{\lambda}$ that satisfies (1) converges. Since the property (1) is inherited by each coordinate, and each $A_\lambda$ is complete, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges coordinate-wise. Let $x$ be its coordinate-wise limit. The triangle inequality implies that for every $\lambda$, 
$$\|x_n^\lambda - x^\lambda\| \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty 2^{-k} = 2^{1-n}$$
Hence $\|x_n  - x \| \le  2^{1-n}\to 0$ as desired.

Comment: How can you use the same $\{x_n\}$ for each element of the product?