# Assume $f(x, \cdot) \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ for a.e. $x \in X$. Then the map $x \mapsto \|f(x, \cdot)\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}}$ is measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let $T>0$ and $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $X :=[0, T]$ and $Y:= \mathbb R^d$. Let $L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ be the space of measurable functions $f:Y \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} := \sup_{y \in Y} \|1_{B(y, 1)} f\|_{L^p} < \infty,
$$
where $B(y, 1)$ is the open unit ball centered at $y$. Then $(L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y), \|\cdot\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}})$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750669/the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-is-complete-w-r-t-the-norm-f) but [not separable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452474/is-the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-separable-w-r-t-the-norm-f). Let $(y_m)$ be a countable dense subset of $Y$. The sphere has Lebesgue measure $0$. Then by dominated convergence theorem (DCT),
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} = \sup_{m \in \mathbb N} \|1_{B(y_m, 1)} f\|_{L^p}
\quad \forall f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y).
$$

I'm trying to prove a statement in a thread, i.e.,

> [(S2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453183/assume-fx-cdot-in-lp-textloc-y-for-a-e-x-in-x-is-f-x-to-l) Let $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ be measurable such that $f(x, \cdot) \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ for a.e. $x \in X$. The map $G: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \|f(x, \cdot)\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}}$ is measurable.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

Let $f_n:X \times Y \to \mathbb R, (x, y) \mapsto f(x, y) 1_{B(y_n, 1)}(y)$. Then $f_n$ is the restriction of $f$ to the measurable subset $X \times B(y_n, 1)$. Then $f_n$ is measurable. Let
$$
F_n: X \to L^p (Y), x \mapsto f_n(x, \cdot),\\
G_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \|f_n(x, \cdot)\|_{L^p}.
$$

Then $G =\sup_n G_n$ everywhere. It suffices to prove that $F_n$ is measurable.

> [Lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452967/99469) Let $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ be measurable such that $f(x, \cdot) \in L^p (Y)$ for a.e. $x \in X$. Then $F: X \to L^p (Y), x \mapsto f(x, \cdot)$ is measurable.

By **Lemma**, $F_n$ is measurable. On the other hand, the norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$ is continuous and thus (Borel) measurable. Then $G_n = \|\cdot\|_{L^p} \circ F_n$ is measurable. This completes the proof.