# If for a.e. $x \in X$ the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is Cauchy in $L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$, then $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $(L^0 (Z), \rho_Z)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let

- $T>0$ and $p \in [1, \infty)$,
- $X :=[0, T]$ and $Y:= \mathbb R^d$,
- $\cal A$ the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $X$,
- $\cal B$ the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$,
- $\mu, \nu$ *complete finite* measures on $X, Y$ respectively,
- $\mu, \nu$ absolutely continuous,
- $Z :=X \times Y$,
- $\cal C$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\cal A$ and $\cal B$,
- $\lambda$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\lambda})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \lambda)$,
- $L^0 (X) := L^0 (X, \mathbb R)$ the space of measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$.

Let $L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ be the space of measurable functions $f:Y \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} := \sup_{y \in Y} \|1_{B(y, 1)} f\|_{L^p} < \infty,
$$
where $B(y, 1)$ is the open unit ball centered at $y$. Let $(y_m)$ be a countable dense subset of $Y$. A sphere is a $\nu$-null set. Then by dominated convergence theorem (DCT),
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} = \sup_{m \in \mathbb N} \|1_{B(y_m, 1)} f\|_{L^p}
\quad \forall f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y).
$$

Let $\rho_Y$ be a [pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pseudometric_space#Definition)  on $L^0(Y)$ defined by
$$
\rho_Y (f, g) := \int_Y \min\{|f-g|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \nu
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (Y).
$$

We define $\rho_Z$ on $L^0(Z)$ similarly. I would like to prove an analogue of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754912/if-for-a-e-x-in-x-the-sequence-f-nx-cdot-n-is-cauchy-in-l1-y-t) result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Assume that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y), \| \cdot\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)})$. Then $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \rho_Z)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

For simplicity, we write
$$
\nu (|f - g| > \delta) := \nu (\{y \in Y : |f (y) - g(y)| > \delta\})
\quad \forall \delta >0, \forall f,g \in L^0 (Y).
$$

Let $\hat \rho_Y$ be another pseudometric on $L^0(Y)$ defined by
$$
\hat \rho_Y (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \nu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (Y).
$$

We define $\hat\rho_Z$ on $L^0(Z)$ similarly. We have some useful properties, i.e.,

> **Lemma 1** $(L^0(Y), \rho_Y)$ is complete.
>
> **Lemma 2** $(L^0(Y), \hat \rho_Y)$ is complete.
>
> **Lemma 3** The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - (S1) $\rho_Y (f_n, f) \to 0$.
> - (S2) Every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $f$ $\nu$-a.e.
> - (S3)  $f_n \to f$ in measure, i.e.,
>   $$
>   \nu (\{y \in Y : |f_n (y)-f(y)| > \varepsilon\}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
>   \quad \forall \varepsilon>0.
>   $$
> - (S4) $\hat \rho_Y (f_n, f) \to 0$.
>
> *Proof*
>
> 1. The proof of the completeness of $\rho_Y$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753822/the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu-measurable-functions-is-complete).
> 2. The proof of the completeness of $\hat\rho_Y$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754648/the-metric-hat-rho-f-g-inf-delta-0-mu-f-g-delta-del).
> 3. The proof of (S1) $\iff$ (S2) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753838/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu). The proof of (S3) $\iff$ (S4) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-finite-measure-is-metrizable). The proof of (S1) $\iff$ (S3) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753870/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-a-finite-measure).

Now we are going to prove our theorem. Assume the contrary that $(f_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \rho_Z)$. By above **Lemmas** $(f_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \hat \rho_Z)$. There is $\varepsilon >0$ and two subsequences $\varphi, \psi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that
$$
\hat \rho_Z (f_{\varphi (n)}, f_{\psi (n)}) \ge \varepsilon
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Then
$$
\lambda (|f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}| > \delta)  +\delta \ge \varepsilon
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N, \forall \delta >0.
$$

We pick $\delta := \varepsilon/2$ and get
$$
\lambda (|f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}| > \varepsilon/2)  \ge \varepsilon/2
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Let $g_n := f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}$. Then $g_n \in L^0(Z)$. We define
$$
h_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \| g_n (x, \cdot) \|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}}.
$$

It has been [verified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756754/assume-fx-cdot-in-lp-textloc-y-for-a-e-x-in-x-then-the-map) that $h_n$ indeed belongs to $L^0 (X)$. By our assumption, $h_n \to 0$ $\mu$-a.e.

> [Lemma 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756802/convergence-in-marginal-measure-implies-that-in-product-measure) Let $g_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $(g_n(x, \cdot))_n \subset L^p_{\text{loc}}  (Y)$. We define
> $$
> h_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \| g_n (x, \cdot) \|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}}.
> $$
> If $\rho_{X} (h_n, 0) \to 0$ then $\rho_Z (g_n, 0) \to 0$.

By **Lemma 4**, $g_n \to 0$ in measure, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.