# Let $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} \to 0$. There is a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $f_{n_k} \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} f$ a.e.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Let $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $Y:= \mathbb R^d$. Let $L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ be the space of measurable functions $f:Y \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} := \sup_{y \in Y} \|1_{B(y, 1)} f\|_{L^p} < \infty,
$$
where $B(y, 1)$ is the open unit ball centered at $y$. Then $(L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y), \|\cdot\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}})$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750669/the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-is-complete-w-r-t-the-norm-f) but [not separable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452474/is-the-space-lp-textloc-mathbb-rd-separable-w-r-t-the-norm-f). Let $(y_m)$ be a countable dense subset of $Y$. The sphere has Lebesgue measure $0$. Then by dominated convergence theorem (DCT),
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} = \sup_{m \in \mathbb N} \|1_{B(y_m, 1)} f\|_{L^p}
\quad \forall f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y).
$$

I would like to prove an analogue of the main result in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301365/convergence-in-mathcal-l-1-implies-mu-a-e-convergence-for-a-subsequence?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f_n, f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} \to 0$. Then there is a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $f_{n_k} \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} f$ a.e.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

Let $f_{n,m} := f_n 1_{B(y_m, 1)}$ and $g_{m} := f 1_{B(y_m, 1)}$. For each $m \ge 1$, we have $\|f_{n, m}-g_m\|_{L^p} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.

- There is a subsequence $\varphi_1$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $f_{\varphi_1 (n), 1} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} g_1$ a.e. Clearly, $\|f_{\varphi_1 (n), 2} - g_2\|_{L^p} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.
- There is a subsequence $\varphi_2$ of $\varphi_1$ such that $f_{\varphi_2 (n), 2} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} g_2$ a.e. Clearly, $\|f_{\varphi_2 (n), 3} - g_3\|_{L^p} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.
- ...

Recursively, there is a sequence $(\varphi_m)$ such that for all $m \ge 1$:

- $\varphi_1$ is a subsequence of $\mathbb N$,
- $\varphi_{m+1}$ is a subsequence of $\varphi_m$, and
- $f_{\varphi_m (n), m} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} g_m$ a.e.

We define a subsequence $\psi$ of $\mathbb N$ by $\psi (m) := \varphi_m (m)$. Then $\psi$ is a subsequence of $\varphi_m$ for every $m \ge 1$. Clearly, $f_{\psi (n)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f$ a.e. This completes the proof.